# In Swift what exactly is the difference between a function that returns a value and one that does not?

Tags: swift, function, concurrency, swift2

Here is some code that I am using in my program

```
func getDate() {
    getTimeRightNow()
    date = timeRightNow
    sendDate()
    print("date was sent")
}

func getTimeRightNow() {
    timeRightNow = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
}
```

The function `getDate()` calls `getTimeRightNow()` which then gets the current `NSDate` and sets it equal to a variable `timeRightNow`. I then take `timeRightNow` and set `date` equal to it which I then pass along for further use.

Below, I have a second version. This time I instead have the `getTimeRightNow()` function return a value of type `Double`...

```
func getDate() {
    date = getTimeRightNow()
    sendDate()
    print("date was sent")
}

func getTimeRightNow()-> Double {
    timeRightNow = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    return timeRightNow
}
```

Both versions seems to work exactly the same. I guess the second version lets me type one less line, is that the only advantage that it offers? Is the second version considered "best practice"? In the second version, is there any chance that the `sendDate()` function gets called BEFORE the `getTimeRightNow()` function finishes and sets a value for `date`? How about in the first version, is there any chance that `timeRightNow` gets set equal to `date` BEFORE the `getTimeRightNow()` function finishes and sets a proper NSDate for `timeRightNow`?

Having trouble understanding this, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the function that has a return value and one that does not is that **it returns a value**. That can be really practical.

```
let aDate = myRandomDate()
let anotherDate = myRandomDate()
```

You would not be able to do this with a function that does not return a value.

Comment: Ok as i was typing out my question that is what I realized but I did not think it was that simple... but it is! Thanks. What about the other part of my question, is it possible that `sendDate()` func gets called before `getTimeRightNow()` func finishes and sets a value for `date`? (or should I ask this in a different question?)

Comment: No, it is not possible that `sendDate()` will be called before `getTimeRightNow()` finishes because they are both called from the same thread. Everything on the one thread runs in sequence. If you enclosed `getTimeRightNow()` in a `dispatch_async`, or something else that ran it in the background, then `sendDate()` might be called before `getTimeRightNow()` finishes - but you don't want that, so you wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Michael thank you! That is the answer I was looking for. I should have made that the title of my question, my fault. The reason I was confused about returns was because I initially got some strange results once I changed my method to the second version I have above, and i thought it might have to do with `sendDate()` being called too soon. Heading off to do some tutorials on Grand Central Dispatch to better understand all this, thanks a lot.